# Archive In-App-Purchase detect png as executables on iOS6

Tags: ios6, png, in-app-purchase

I have created a pack In-App-Purchase on iOS6. I upload content to apple´s server. The packet has a group of png files. If I use the option:

```
Compress PNG Files = YES
```

The pngs uploaded to the server and downloaded on the App are corrupts and I cannot open it. If I open the content downloaded from the App, I cannot open with GIMP or Photoshop.

So I put:

```
Compress PNG Files = NO
```

But when I try upload the content as I do the last time, I get the following error making the distributable:

```
The archive for In-App-Purchase: 'com.myapp.ProjectName.myInAppPack' is invalid. The package contains an executable at 'Content/file3.png'
```

This error appear 2 times, but I have 10 pngs. I made exactly following the same steps for all of them, but 2 are detected as executables.

I sure that is a problem with headers, How can I edit them to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After open the files with Exfiend and compare it, I found the problem was the headers. The pngs detected as executables had a Photoshop header. I have solved the problem creating a new png, copying the layer, exporting as png.

Then, I put only read flags on PNGs files with:

```
chmod 444 file.png
```

After clean the inapppurchase project, and archive it, it did fine.

Comment: Thanks, chmod 444 works with other file types detected as executable.